# VBA run from cmd line doesn't work but in Excel Macro editor is ok

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a strange issue in my small VBA/Excel app. I've got a vbs script which starts an Excel Macro:

```
Option Explicit
Dim excelObject

Set excelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

excelObject.DisplayAlerts = False
excelObject.AskToUpdateLinks = False
excelObject.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

excelObject.WorkBooks.Open "C:\test\test.xlsm", 0, True
excelObject.Run "Make_Output.Update_Data_In_Another_Excel_Document"
excelObject.Quit(0)
```

this Excel Macro opens another Excel document and modifies some data there.

My problem happens when I run it from command line. Sometimes I receive error : "File not found: " exception although I haven't changed anything in the app. For instance when I run the app on another machine. When I open the Excel doc and run it manually from Excel Macro editor all is fine. I have no idea what can be the issue although I've already went through the manual. Maybe it is connected with compilation of macros by EXCEL.

[image]

Additional info:
Version: Microsoft Excel 2010 - 14.0.7015 - 32-bit but my system is 64-bit

Any hints appreciated.
Thanks.
foxrafi

Comment: Maybe on another machine there is no test.xlsm in C:\test\ ?

Comment: I don't see any reasons why this wouldn't work with command line. Maybe the error comes from `Make_Output.Update_Data_In_Another_Excel_Document`

Answer (score 0):

My VBScript File (OpenExcel.vbs)

```
Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xlApp  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

File = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName) & _
       "\run this to open other files macro.xlsm"

 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

 Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(File)

     xlApp.Visible = True 'or False
     xlApp.Run "'C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\testvbscript.xlsm'!TestVBScript"
```

The Macro in that sheet

```
Sub Meow()

    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\testvbscript.xlsm")
    objExcel.Visible = True

    objExcel.Run "'C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\testvbscript.xlsm'!TestVBScript"

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

    objExcel.Quit

    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then the last macro to open random file to modify cell

```
Sub TestVBScript()

 MsgBox "Running VBScript to run this macro worked."

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fs.FileExists("C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\test.xlsx") Then

   Set FileToModify = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\test.xlsx")
   Set OpenFile = FileToModify.Sheets("Sheet1")

   OpenFile.Cells(1, "A").Value = "OOOHHH YEAAHHHH."
   FileToModify.Save
   FileToModify.Close
   Debug.Print "yes"

Else

   Debug.Print "no"

End If

End Sub
```